# How to manage an array of strings in onBindViewHolder method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a restaurant app and I want to build my products menu as a recyclerview, containing in each cardview the image, name, ingredients, price and other buttons. I have a problem building the ingredients array of strings, as I want to add them based on my Firebase datas for each product. This is my product class:

```
public class MenuObject {
private String image, name, quantity,  price;
private int increment, decrement, button;
private String[] ingredients;

public MenuObject(){}

public MenuObject(String image, String name, String[] ingredients, String price, int increment, String quantity, int decrement, int button){
    this.image = image;
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.price = price;
    this.increment = increment;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.decrement = decrement;
    this.button = button;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String[] getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}
public void setIngredients(String[] ingredients) {
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getDecrement() {
    return decrement;
}
public void setDecrement(int decrement) {
    this.decrement = decrement;
}

public int getIncrement() {
    return increment;
}
public void setIncrement(int increment) {
    this.increment = increment;
}

public int getButton() {
    return button;
}
public void setButton(int button) {
    this.button = button;
}
```

And this is the line from method which gives me trouble:

```
holder.ingredients.setText(currentMenuObject.getIngredients());
```

However, in my adapter an error message shows saying:

> no suitable method found for setText(String[])
>   holder.ingredients.setText(currentMenuObject.getIngredients()); method
>   TextView.setText(CharSequence) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to CharSequence)
>       method TextView.setText(int) is not applicable

I don't know how to manage an array of strings in my onBindViewHolder method or if I need to change something in my class.

Comment: how do you want to show the string array for ingredients? like comma-separated or something else. Please mention that

Comment: Yes, I would like to put a comma between them.

Comment: If you are using Java 8 you can try to join ingredients array to String using `String.join(", ", menuObject.getIngredients())`. Just to make your app run. I do not think this is the solution you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set an array of strings to `TextView` `setText` method. You have to append the strings from the array to create a single string. Then set it to your `TextView`.

For example :

```
if(currentMenuObject.getIngredients() != null) {
       String str ="";
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : currentMenuObject.getIngredients()) {
                str.append(",").append(s);
            }

    if (currentMenuObject.getIngredients().length > 0) {
        str.deleteCharAt(0); // remove first comma
    }
        holder.ingredients.setText(str.toString());
}
```

This will add the string array's value separated by comma(",").

Comment: With this my app crashes and gives me the "Attempt to get length of null array" error at for loop.

Comment: it means currentMenuObject.getIngredients() is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is telling you exactly what's wrong: `setText()` expects an argument of type `CharSequence` (like a `String`), but you give it a `String[]`. So what you want to do is convert your array of ingredient names to a String, like:

```
String text = Arrays.toString(currentMenuObject.getIngredients());
holder.ingredients.setText(text); // [ingredient1, ..., ingredientn]
```

or more likely you want to do it like this (API26+):

```
String text = String.join(",", currentMenuObject.getIngredients());
holder.ingredients.setText(text); // ingredient1, ..., ingredientn
```

or with a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String ingredient : currentMenuObject.getIngredients()) {
    builder.append(ingredient).append(",");
}
if (currentMenuObject.getIngredients().length > 0) {
    builder.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); // remove last comma again
}

String text = builder.toString();
holder.ingredients.setText(text); // ingredient1, ..., ingredientn
```